# Can't make a new Jekyll project

Tags: bash, terminal, jekyll

I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

I can create projects but for some reason they end up being creating in a directory that I don't even have access to. I am quite new to terminals. Does anybody know how to fix this (i.e. how to create a project in a directory that I actually have on my computer)?

[image: Where is /home/[username]/test123 supposed to be on Windows?]

As you can see in the screenshot, the new project has been installed in /home/[my username]/test123. That directory doesn't exist on my computer.

Edit: Can I get some help instead of being mercilessly downvoted?

Comment: It looks all like it should be. I assume you are executing the command in your home folder. I am surprised you can't see the test123 folder. Have you tested using "ls -al ~" to actually check it? Have you tried to make a directory manually to see if you can actually do that, like "mkdir test555" or something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty lost right now. This might sound silly, but I actually don't think that ANY of the folders that I see on bash are actually on my computer. (http://imgur.com/l8iUUmQ). When I type "ls -al ~", I get a bunch of information but I have no idea how I can put that info to good use. In regards to making a directory, I tried to, but it just seems to me like I am making folders in a completely separate laptop. I can't find any of those directories on my physical computer. It's like I am looking at another computer's directory

Comment: We all had to start one time. ;-) When you type "cd /" you are moving up to the root directory. This is more or less like C:/. You should not work in there. You only work in your /home/<Username> directory. Can you open a a new shell (it should give you the homes directory). Then type "mkdir testSOF" and finally "ls -al". You should then see a folder called "testSOF". Can you confirm that?

Comment: confirmed. I see it.

Comment: Wonderful. can you now try to "jekyll new whatever" from exactly the same place and hit "ls -al" again?

Comment: Hey, sorry about the late reply! I created the project and when I type ls -al, that project shows up in the same directory as testSOF (not inside it).

Comment: Yes that's correct then. The command basically creates a new folder at the location where you are at the moment. You should now be able to "cd whatever" and run "jekyll build". If that's actually happening, you can work from there and I will rephrase all that to a proper answer.

Comment: Oh wow, when I typed "jekyll build", I got a lot of warnings about "previous definitions" and "already initialized constant Sass::Util::.....". then I got an error immediately after saying "Error: superclass mismatch for class mapping"

Comment: I am not sure what that actually is, but I believe this is related to the Windows build. Jekyll started to exist on Mac/Linux first. There might be a lot of bugs in that implementation, I don't know. My advise is to move that to a different question for better visibility. Also consider https://talk.jekyllrb.com and/or open a bug report to the Jekyll team directly.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your advice. It's incredible how frustrating this thing can be.  Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I fully understand that. To be honest, I would advise any developer to use either Linux or MacOS for developing today. But well, I might be biased. It's just, I rarely have problems like these :-/

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to notice how much harder it is to do things in Windows sometimes, oh well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145921/discussion-between-alwayslearning-and-christian).

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this. https://askubuntu.com/a/759885/59053 I start believing you are "just" looking into the wrong directory :)

Comment: Hey Christian, good to hear from you again. I actually was the guy that posted the question on talk.jekyllrb.com yesterday and I ended up finding the answer to this question. Thanks

Comment: If you want help rather than downvotes, a good place to start would be to ask a question that's on-topic. Jekyll is potentially on-topic, but "I don't understand my operating system's filesystem" is not -- that's a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [UNIX SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). It doesn't help that you say "that directory doesn't exist on my computer", but don't specify anything about how you reach that conclusion or otherwise provide evidence for same.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a solution from a [query in Jekyll's own forum](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-on-windows-cannot-locate-directory-after-creating-a-new-project/618):

> Apparently, the root directory for "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" is **`C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs`** ([More Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice)).

The project file you create can be found in the path mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is that my directory looks nothing like C:. It looks like a directory that you would typically find in Linux or mac (/home/user/...) and since I don't have that directory on my computer, I can't access the jekyll projects that I create at all. If the directory was C:/.... then all I would have to do is create the project and then simply look for that directory on my computer to find the folder. That directory is not in my computer at all and that is the main issue

Comment: Posted a solution from Jekyll Talk

Comment: Note that Microsoft **strongly** advises against interacting with the contents of this directory with Windows-based applications -- doing so will destroy the permission metadata on the file and make them unavailable from Linux, *if* it even works. Thus, inasmuch as this answer is true, using or taking advantage of it in any way is, in short, a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/